# Passing a pointer-to-member function into template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, c++17

I wonder how can I pass a pointer to the non-static member function into the template?
Here's the simplified code:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct contains;

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Ts>
struct contains<T, R(Ts...)>
{
    static constexpr bool result = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;
};

class A
{
public:
    static void staticFoo(int a, double* b) {}
    void foo(int a, double* b) {}
};
void foo(int a, double* b) {}

int main ()
{
    //ok, this works
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains<double*, decltype(foo)>::result;
    //this too
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains<double*, std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(&A::staticFoo)>>::result;
    //boom, error
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains<double*, decltype(&A::foo)>::result;

    return 0;
}
```

Executing this code, I got an error:

```
 incomplete type 'contains<double*, void (A::*)(int, double*)>' used in nested name specifier
```

As I understood, types are:

```
void(int, double*)
void(*)(int, double*)
void(A::*)(int, double*)
```

In the second case I can use `std::remove_pointer_t`, but how can I remove `(A::*)` from function signature in the third case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add other specializations:

```
template<typename, typename> struct contains;

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Ts>
struct contains<T, R(Ts...)>
{
    static constexpr bool result = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;
};

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Ts>
struct contains<T, R (*)(Ts...)> : contains<T, R(Ts...)>
{
};

template<typename T, typename C, typename R, typename... Ts>
struct contains<T, R (C::*)(Ts...)> : contains<T, R(Ts...)>
{
};

// And even more for R (C::*) (Ts... ...) const volatile &&
```

And then

```
int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains<double*, decltype(foo)>::result;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains<double*, decltype(&A::staticFoo)>::result;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains<double*, decltype(&A::foo)>::result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So there's no way to cut class name from function signature, only to write some other specialization?